# if else not working js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Code i just want to change x value on click if it is x then change y ..if it is y then change to x again but after become y value cant change to x .. the control is always on 3rd section .. whats wrong

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           var x;
          $(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
          if(x == null){

          alert('section 1' );
            x = 'X';
           }
          else if(x == 'X'){
          alert('section 2');
             x = 'Y';
           }
          else if(x == 'Y'){
          alert('section 3');
                x == 'X';
           }
            $(this).html(x);
          })

        });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fsdrqo1t/ - In this fiddle section 1 is alerting which is expected

Comment: thanks ssilas and everyone to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two mistakes, one ; missing and x == X which should x = X

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           var x;
          $(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
              if(x == null){
                    alert('section 1' );
                    x = 'X';
               } else if(x == 'X'){
                    alert('section 2');
                    x = 'Y';
               } else if(x == 'Y'){
                    alert('section 3');
                    x = 'X';
               }
            $(this).html(x);
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('section 3');
x == 'X';
```

should be

```
alert('section 3');
x = 'X';
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gjktn9p/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra '=' in the last else if statement!

x = 'X'; should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using comparison operator after `alert('Section 3')`. Instead you must use assignment operator! Try this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var x;
  $(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
  if(x == null){
    alert('section 1' );
    x = 'X';
  } else if(x == 'X') {
    alert('section 2');
    x = 'Y';
  } else if(x == 'Y') {
    alert('section 3');
    x = 'X';
  }
  $(this).html(x);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You added one more `=` in the third section.
Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               var x;
              $(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
              if(x == null){

              alert('section 1' );
                x = 'X';
               }
              else if(x == 'X'){
              alert('section 2');
                 x = 'Y';
               }
              else if(x == 'Y'){
              alert('section 3');
                    x = 'X';
               }
                $(this).html(x);
              });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `x == 'X';` to `x = 'X'` as you have to assign a value x=='X' does Nothing. If you put comparions Or ternary operator like `x =='X'?If true then do this:else this;` in if then it gives you true or false result

Answer (score 0):

```
    Used assignment operator instead of comparison operator in Third section
    try this code.

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var x;
      $(".ticktack tr td").click(function(){
      if(x == null){

      alert('section 1' );
        x = 'X';
       }
      else if(x == 'X'){
      alert('section 2');
         x = 'Y';
       }
      else if(x == 'Y'){
      alert('section 3');
            x = 'X';
       }
        $(this).html(x);
      })

    });
```